# Removing/Deleting a UserClaim in MembershipReboot with Guid keys failing

Tags: guid, claims, membershipreboot

I am working on a project and using MembershipReboot as the membership manager. I am using Guids for the keys instead of the ints used in the Single Tenant demo. My application can add UserClaims but I get an error when trying to remove or delete them. Some error about not being able to set a foreign key to null. There is only one foreign key in UserClaim, the ParentKey. I don't think the framework should be setting it to null anyway, it should be simply deleting the UserClaim, not modifying it. I can fix this by scanning the repository for modified UserClaims and deleting them, but this is a horrible kludge. I was just wondering if anyone else has used UserClaim and if they worked for them?

MembershipReboot Version 7.2.

Comment: Are you calling ConfigureMembershipRebootUserAccounts in your custom DbContext's OnModelCreating?

Comment: Yes I am. Most of the Membership stuff works as expected, registration of users, resetting passwords, changing e-mails, etc.